# Difference between @timestamp and timestamp field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, kibana

When I logged some requests to elastic search using log stash, it puts @timestamp field as time.
And when I logged those requests using NEST and set timestamp field, it puts timestamp field.

When I see data using kibana, those 2 fields have separate name. What is difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @timestamp field is kind of an internal field for log stash. That is why the @ sign is in front of the field. Could be any other field that stores a timestamp. Just like elasticsaerch uses the _ for some internal fields.