# timestamp issue in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp, kibana

I have an issue similar to this [Difference between @timestamp and timestamp field in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901336/difference-between-timestamp-and-timestamp-field-in-elasticsearch). But I will need solution for it.

We use Kibana which by default use @timestamp as time filter. Yes, I can change it to whatever field  manually EVERYTIME people create the time filter, but it is impossible for EVERYBODY in our big team to know it.  So we need @timestamp.

@timestamp won't show up even I use the mapping here,

```
"_timestamp" : {
    "enabled" : true,
    "store" : true
}
```

So I workaround by adding a field name called @timestamp. I can use curl to add documents to it and The time filer start working.

However, when I move to use NEST api which cannot create @timestamp field. Even I define the field name as @timestamp, NEST api automatically change it to timestamp.

So Kibana time filter broken again.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. Nest API does have a way to explicitly set the field name.

```
[ElasticProperty(Name = "@timestamp", Type = FieldType.Date, DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Store = true)]
```

So this is resolved.

Comment: What does this look like in the newer versions of nest?