# Elastic search count query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am trying to find occurences of a specific pattern within a given period of time.
I don't get the count for that pattern with `Query 1` which has time parameter, but works with `Query 2`.
Can you please if there is any issue with `Query 1`.

#### Query 1:

```
GET/_count?pretty{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "Stopping PSB: start the yum-updateonboot deamon..."
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "gt": "now-1d"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'  Result: {   **"count" : 0,**   "_shards" : {     "total" : 2287,     "successful" : 2287,     "skipped" : 0,     "failed" : 0   }
```

Query 2:

```
GET/_count?pretty{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "Stopping PSB: start the yum-updateonboot deamon..."
        }
      }
    }
  }
}Result: {
  "count": 280483,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2287,
    "successful": 2287,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  }
```

Comment: Can you share your index mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [date math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math) with `d`ays is somewhat [confusing](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/several-date-math-questions/27453).

Use either hours:

```
{
  "range":{
    "@timestamp":{
      "gt":"now-24h"
    }
  }
}
```

or `gte` instead of `gt`:

```
{
  "range":{
    "@timestamp":{
      "gte":"now-1d"
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**

Use `timestamp` instead of `@timestamp`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "Stopping PSB: start the yum-updateonboot deamon..."
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "gt": "now-1d"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26904932/8160318) and [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-is-the-difference-between-timestamp-and-timestamp/46464/2).

Comment: Tried both and still don't see the count.GET /_count?pretty
{
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
               "query_string":{
                 "query":"Stopping PSB: start the yum-updateonboot deamon..."
}
        },
   "filter":{      
   "range":{
     "@timestamp":{
            "gte":"now-1d"

}
}
 
   }       
    }
}
}

Comment: Then there are no docs matching that query. Are you sure there should be some matches? What if you remove the query string part?

Comment: When i search in kibana,there are matching docs in last 1 hour.

Comment: Let me know if this is good enough.  {
  "_index": "conlog-2020-06-08-11-35",
  "_type": “MMJ”,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "gid": "0",
    "message": "Started PSB: start the yum-updateonboot deamon.",
    "pid": "1",
    "priority": "6",
    "uid": "0",
    "host": “MMJ.net",
    "processed": "2020-06-08T12:06:32.507327Z",
    "timestamp": "2020-06-08T12:06:32.192205+00:00",
    "persona": “MMJ”
  },
  "fields": {
    "processed": [
      "2020-06-08T12:06:32.507Z"
    ],
    "timestamp": [
      "2020-06-08T12:06:32.192Z"
    ]
  }
}